# Add method for multiple arrays and ToString?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly I would put in one of my classes to create the add method for 3 Arrays of the same Type. Here are the generic arrays in the main class

```
   ArrayContainer<Integer> numberContainer = new ArrayContainer<>();
   ArrayContainer<String> wordContainer = new ArrayContainer<>();
   ArrayContainer<Pokemon> pokedex = new ArrayContainer<>();
```

My constructor for ArrayContainer is

```
public ArrayContainer(){
       container = (T[]) new Object[defaultSize];
       numItems = 0;
   }
```

In my separate class, I'm confused what to put for my

```
public void add (T item){}
```

and I'm confused as what to return within my toString. I know you add to an array by putting

```
arrayName[index] = whatever;
```

But what would I put in that add method that would add to whatever array I call the method on? Would it be container[index] = item;?

What should I return that would return the element in the array?

Comment: You're basically re-writing an ArrayList. See the source code for ideas http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

Comment: As the question currently stands it's very broad. Try to narrow the question down to a specific problem. You can always ask new questions after solving that.

Answer (score 1):

- Since the number of items in your `ArrayContainer` is not known beforehand, you should use a *dynamic* array, also known as **[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)**.
- The `numItems` then becomes redundant since you can get it by calling `list.size()`
- Your `add` function will only need to call `list.add`. As noted in the comments, it seems you're re-writing/wrapping `List`
- In your `toString` method, you can return a *string* that concatenates all results of `toString` of the items included. [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) can help you create a "format" that suits you. Of course this means that the objects you're putting in the container need to implement [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Combining all the things will give you something like this:

## ArrayContainer

```
public class ArrayContainer<T> {
    private List<T> items;

    public ArrayContainer() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[ ");
        for (T it: items)
            sb.append(it.toString()).append(' ');

        sb.append(']');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

## Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayContainer<String> stringArrayContainer = new ArrayContainer<>();
        stringArrayContainer.add("hello");
        stringArrayContainer.add("world");

        System.out.println(stringArrayContainer);
        // Outputs: [hello world]
    }
}
```